# Optimal Kakfa Connect Hourly S3AvroSink Config

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

```
{
  "name":"{{name}}",
  "tasks.max": "6", //have 6 partitions for this topic
  "topics": "{{topic}}",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
  "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
  "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "xx",
  "key.converter.key.subject.name.strategy": "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy",
  "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
  "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "xx",
  "value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy": "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy",
  "errors.retry.timeout":"600000",
  "errors.log.enable":"true",
  "errors.log.include.messages":"true",



  "schema.compatibility": "BACKWARD",

  "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.avro.AvroFormat",
  "flush.size": "100000",
  "rotate.schedule.interval.ms": "3600000",
  "rotate.interval.ms": "3600000",
  "enhanced.avro.schema.support": "true",
  "connect.meta.data": "false",


  "partitioner.class": "{{partitioner}}somepartitioner",
  "partition.duration.ms": "3600000",
  "path.format": "'avro/event=?eventClass?/tenant=?tenant?/date'=YYYY-MM-dd/'hour'=HH",
  "locale": "en",
  "timezone": "UTC",
  "timestamp.extractor": "RecordField",
  "timestamp.field": "{{timestampField}}",



  "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",


  "s3.bucket.name": "somebucket",
  "s3.region": "region",
  "s3.part.size": "5242880",


  "offset.flush.interval.ms": "1200000"
}
```

The count for the topic is around 739,180 and size 1.1Gb

I'm not fully sure if my config is fully correct or not, if i can improve it somehwere. I want to flush in two cases,  hourly or if the size hits 5gb.

Comment: So, first, you should not use both `rotate.*.ms` properties. Also, there's no way to write files based on file size, only number of messages. So, if you know the average size of each record, you can approximate needed the flush.size.... Also, if you get different Avro schemas within the topic, a file is always written when that happens

Comment: which one should I use? And how can i get the avg record size. above mentioned count/total size. 739,180/1.1gb(converted into kb). i see two files in the s3 hourly path. each with few kbs size.

Comment: For the rotation, refer - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/issues/177#issuecomment-402249805 and like I said, if you get differing avro records in the topic, then you should expect many tiny files, and you'd need to fix your all the producers to be on the same version. Otherwise, I have no other suggestion for making larger files; your only options are time-based (with a very large record count) or record-count based (with a large rotation time), or some combination of both

Comment: thanks, I think I got most of it. I would have to watch the producer to further make any changes